# Concatenar y fusionar columnas en python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ciencia-de-datos

estoy intentando fusionar 2 dataframe que poseen la misma cantidad de filas(Provienen de realizar get_dummies()),

Ejemplo:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]}, index = [1,2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[5,6], 'c':[5,4]}, index = [1,2])
print(df1)
print('******')
print(df2)

  a  b
1  1  3
2  2  4
******
   b  c
1  5  5
2  6  4
```

**El resultado final esperado.**

```
    a   b   c
1   1   8   5
2   2   10  4
```

En un comienzo he utilizado

```
d = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
d

    a   b   b   c
1   1   3   5   5
2   2   4   6   4
```

Son muchas columnas para hacer la operación de suma una a una adicional a que no se reconocen fácilmente cuales se duplican.

también he intentado con error o sin el resultado esperado realizando diferentes funciones y configuraciones.

```
d = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key') 
d

d = df1.join(df2)
d
```

Agradezco las ideas de cual podría ser la mejor solución.

Saludos

PD: A nivel general la duda o el manejo se da por que se están pasando de categóricas a numéricas varias columnas correspondientes a códigos de actividades que se pueden repetir. al concatenar se generan columnas repetidas las cuales quisiera que se sumaran.

```
dp_1 = pd.concat([data, pd.get_dummies(data['cod act'])], axis = 1)
dp_2 = pd.concat([dp_1, pd.get_dummies(dp_1['cod act 1'])], axis = 1)
dp_3 = pd.concat([dp_2, pd.get_dummies(dp_2['cod act 2'])], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre, es generalizar al menos el procedimiento de suma, de las columnas con el mismo nombre. Partiendo de la concatenación inicial que has hecho:

```
d = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

La idea sería sumar por fila cada columna repetida:

```
from collections import Counter

cols_repetidas = [col for col, cant in Counter(d.columns).items() if cant > 1]
cols_unicas = [col for col in d.columns if col not in cols_repetidas]
new_df = d[cols_unicas]

for col in cols_repetidas:
  new_df.insert(len(new_df.columns), col, d[col].sum(axis=1))

print(new_df)

   a  c   b
1  1  5   8
2  2  4  10
```